# PYTHON convert list of strings to JSON array of objects with key and value

Tags: python, arrays, json, arraylist, arrayofstring

I'm using **PYTHON** :

I'm trying to convert the following array of strings:

```
tags_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

to an array of JSON array of objects with a specific key as follows:

```
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "name": "two"
        },
        {
            "name": "three"
        }
    ]
```

I found several answers for JavaScript not python

Can any body help please

Thanks in-advance

Comment: Can you translate the javascript to python?

Comment: `json_dict = {"tags": [{"name": value} for value in tags_list]}` does the thing. Any explanations needed?

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as @sudden_appearance mentioned, but I'd add :

```
print(json.dumps(json_dict, indent=2))
```

when you log it to the console, for a better format :)

Answer (score 3):

**try this is full example of your code**

```
import json
tags_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

#prepare array to object
json_dict = {"tags": [{"name": value} for value in tags_list]}

#object to json String
json_string= json.dumps(json_dict)
print(json_string) #for print json if needed
```